# Install Ubuntu with current setup and apps to OS-free PC

Tags: system-installation, clone, disk-image

I have Ubuntu installed, with some small apps and scripts running on it. I need to deploy this current setup to other PCs.

Until now whenever I needed this setup I just installed it manually to other PCs.

Is there any way I could make an image or a clone or something of this PC and just deploy it? Something like a clean install but with the scripts and apps added there